# How to keep values after click the input button in php?

Tags: php, html

There are three form elements: startdate, enddate, and select box.

```
  <input type="date" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" placeholder="Start" id = startdate value='<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>'/>
  <input type="date" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" placeholder="End" id = enddate value='<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>'/>
</div>
<div class="mb-4">
  <h5 class="mb-4">Selection</h5>
  <select class="form-control select2-single" name = "model" id = "model" data-width="100%">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and after I click the button like this

```
<div class = "col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
  <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-shadow" id = "btn1" type="submit" name = "search"  value="입력" ></input>
</div>
```

I want to keep the startdate value, enddate value, and selected option value.

This is my php code which processes the input values:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search']))
{
  $startDate = $_POST['start'];
  $startDate = str_replace('/', '-', $startDate ); 
  $startDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($startDate));
  // echo $startDate;
                                                
  $endDate = $_POST['end'];
  $endDate = str_replace('/', '-', $endDate ); 
  $endDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($endDate));
  // echo $endDate;

  $model = $_POST['model'];
  // echo $model;
```

How to edit my code?

Comment: You got to select values in form according with received data. You can draw your form options with PHP, checking for each one if is the selected, and draw selected propery for that concrete option tag.

Answer (score 0):

For the dates it's a simple echo. For the dropdown you need to add `selected` to the option which matches the previous input.

You also need to account for the scenario where no input was received (because it's the first time the form is being loaded) and set some defaults.

N.B. Your date-processing code is all totally unnecessary, as the date is sent from an `<input type="date"` in `yyyy-mm-dd` format already.

So, you neeed something like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search']))
{
  $startDate = $_POST['start'];
  $endDate = $_POST['end'];
  $model = $_POST['model'];
}
else
{
  $startDate = date('Y-m-d');
  $endDate = date('Y-m-d');
  $model = "";
}

$modelVals = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
```

...

```
  <input type="date" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" placeholder="Start" id="startdate" value="<?php echo $startDate;?>" />
  <input type="date" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" placeholder="End" id="enddate" value="<?php echo $endDate;?>" />
</div>
<div class="mb-4">
<h5 class="mb-4">Selection</h5>
  <select class="form-control select2-single" name = "model" id = "model" data-width="100%">
  <?php
  foreach ($modelVals as $val) {
    echo '<option value="A"'.($val == $model ? "selected" : "").'>'.$val.'</option>';
  ?>
  </select>
</div>
```